# Delete file with filename that contain unallowed characters

Tags: files, filesystems

In `/tmp` dir I have file with this filename:

`.<?php passthru($_GET['cmd']);echo 'm3rg3';?>`

I can't remove this file by normal means and have tried with quoting this filename with no results.

What should I try next?

Comment: Use single quotes or tab completion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ls -li` to see the inode them remove the inode with `find`

```
[root@server tmp]# ls -li .\<*
16163346 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 23 12:02 .<?php  passthru($_GET[cmd]);echo 
[root@server tmp]# find . -inum 16163346 -exec rm -i {} \;
rm: remove regular empty file `./.<?php passthru($_GET[cmd]);echo'? y
```

Reference: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-remove-files-with-inode-number.html

Comment: OK, that's really clever. I knew about `-inum` but never thought of a use for it before.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
rm -iv -- .\<\?php\ passthru\(\$_GET\[cmd\]\)\;echo\ m3rg3\;\?\>
```

And for future, when you have really weird filename try to make use of the shell *glob* mechanism, for example:

```
ls .*php*
```

should be a good start. If you have many files with similar filenames, just use any unique regular substring

```
ls .*php*cmd*echo*m3rg3*
```

And at the end you can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete the filename if the shell you are using has completion mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` is a smart beast, you can use `glob patterns` in the argument

For your case a simple `rm .\<*` is sufficient

<sub>*be careful when using `rm` with `glob patterns` as it will delete multiple files matching the pattern</sub>

Comment: (1) The fact that this works doesn't really have anything to do with the intelligence of `rm`.  The shell is smart; `rm` just sees a filename argument.  (Or several filename arguments, if you have multiple files whose names begin with `.<`.) (2) This doesn't really add anything to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

### `find` GNU or not GNU

With the GNU version of `find` you can write directly, without seeking for their inode,

```
find . -name '.<*' -delete
```

of course it's always suggested to try before without the `-delete` option and check the name of the files you are going to delete.

With a non GNU version too it could be done directly `find . -name '.<*' -exec rm -i {} \;` that works also with the GNU version, only about 3 times slower <sup>[[1](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux)]</sup> then with `-delete`.
When there are not too many files you can use too `find . -name '.<*' -exec rm -i {} +`, again faster.

### `perl`

Assuming  `.<*` as key that selects all and only the files you want to delete (not without some *gym* on the string)

```
perl -e 'for(<'.'\<'*'>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

<sup>To delete all the hidden files of the directory it is enough `perl -e 'for(<'.*'>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'`</sup>

It is faster with a lot of files. Check for the expression because I don't work usually with perl.

### Workaround

In general you can try to move all the other files in another directory and delete the original directory

```
mv /tmp /tmp2; mkdir tmp; mv /tmp2/* /tmp; rm tmp2
```

Drawbacks if some file are in use... but there are cases in which you can use it too.

Ps> do not forget `rsync` to `/dev/null` with the `-delete` option...